# data.table - select first n rows within group

Tags: r, data.table

As simple as it is, I don't know a `data.table` solution to select the first n rows in groups in a data table. Can you please help me out?

Comment: this is very close to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110616/throw-away-first-and-last-n-rows

Comment: The question this closed question is a duplicate of includes [an answer using `dt[rowid(cyl)<3]` that is up to almost 100x faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73312825/1870254).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As an alternative:

```
dt[, .SD[1:3], cyl]
```

When you look at speed on the example dataset, the `head` method is on par with the [`.I` method of @eddi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325641/in-r-is-it-possible-to-extact-the-first-2-rows-for-each-date-from-a-data-table#comment23381259_16325932). Comparing with the `microbenchmark` package:

```
microbenchmark(head = dt[, head(.SD, 3), cyl],
               SD = dt[, .SD[1:3], cyl], 
               I = dt[dt[, .I[1:3], cyl]$V1],
               times = 10, unit = "relative")
```

results in:

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 head 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000    10  a 
   SD 2.156562 2.319538 2.306065 2.365190 2.318540 2.1908401    10   b
    I 1.001810 1.029511 1.007371 1.018514 1.016583 0.9442973    10  a
```

However, `data.table` is specifically designed for large datasets. So, running this comparison again:

```
# creating a 30 million dataset
largeDT <- dt[,.SD[sample(.N, 1e7, replace = TRUE)], cyl]
# running the benchmark on the large dataset
microbenchmark(head = largeDT[, head(.SD, 3), cyl],
               SD = largeDT[, .SD[1:3], cyl], 
               I = largeDT[largeDT[, .I[1:3], cyl]$V1],
               times = 10, unit = "relative")
```

results in:

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
 head 2.279753 2.194702 2.221330 2.177774 2.276986 2.33876    10   b
   SD 2.060959 2.187486 2.312009 2.236548 2.568240 2.55462    10   b
    I 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000    10  a
```

Now the `.I` method is clearly the fastest one.

---

***Update 2016-02-12:***

With the most recent development version of the *data.table* package, the `.I` method still wins. Whether the `.SD` method or the `head()` method is faster seems to depend on the size of the dataset. Now the benchmark gives:

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 head 2.093240 3.166974 3.473216 3.771612 4.136458 3.052213    10   b
   SD 1.840916 1.939864 2.658159 2.786055 3.112038 3.411113    10   b
    I 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10  a
```

However with a somewhat smaller dataset (but still quite big), the odds change:

```
largeDT2 <- dt[,.SD[sample(.N, 1e6, replace = TRUE)], cyl]
```

the benchmark is now slightly in favor of the `head` method over the `.SD` method:

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 head 1.808732 1.917790 2.087754 1.902117 2.340030 2.441812    10   b
   SD 1.923151 1.937828 2.150168 2.040428 2.413649 2.436297    10   b
    I 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10  a
```

Comment: Was this done with 1.9.7? I know some operations with `.SD` have recently been optimized...

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, but I'm using a relatively old version of 1.9.7 (shortly after the introduction of `rowid`). So, it depends on how recent recently is ;-)

Comment: I think the relevant commits were around the beginning of November

Comment: performance may depends on cardinality of `cyl`

Comment: I don't find the same results anymore, I find `.SD` faster than `head` faster than `.I`. @Jaap do you consider updating your answer ? :)

Comment: @SamuelAllain I still get more or less the same result. However this might be due to the number of threads `data.table` is using (this benchmark is run with 1 thread). Its on my todo-list to enable `openmp` on my machine so I can test with more threads.

Comment: @Jaap thanks for testing again. I tested with setDTthreads(1) but still didn't find your results. I think @jangorecki is right, the results highly depend on the the cardinality of the grouping variable. When cardinality is under 6, `.I` wins for me, but otherwise, .SD and head are faster.

Comment: I made a simulation with moving cardinality, It indeed affects the ranking of methods. I cannot post my graph on this topic, unfortunately.

Answer (score 19):

We can use `head` with `.SD`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(mtcars)

> dt[, head(.SD, 3), by = "cyl"]

   cyl  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:   6 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2:   6 21.0 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3:   6 21.4 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4:   4 22.8 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
5:   4 24.4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
6:   4 22.8 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
7:   8 18.7 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
8:   8 14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
9:   8 16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
```

Comment: note that actually `head.data.table`  (`getAnywhere("head.data.table")`) is just calling a (slightly more robust) version of @Jaap's answer.