# Subset first n occurrences of certain value in dataframe

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix (or dataframe):

```
1  5  8
3  4  9
3  9  6
6  9  3
3  1  2
4  7  2
3  8  6
3  2  7
```

I would like to select only the first three rows that have "3" as their first entry, as follows:

```
3  4  9
3  9  6
3  1  2
```

It is clear to me how to pull out all rows that begin with "3" and it is clear how to pull out just the first row that begins with "3."

But in general, how can I extract the first n rows that begin with "3"?

Furthermore, how can I select just the 3rd and 4th appearances, as follows:

```
3  1  2
3  8  6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the need for an extra package:

```
mydf[mydf$V1==3,][1:3,]
```

results in:

```
  V1 V2 V3
2  3  4  9
3  3  9  6
5  3  1  2
```

When you need the third and fourth row:

```
mydf[mydf$V1==3,][3:4,]
# or:
mydf[mydf$V1==3,][c(3,4),]
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), 
                       V2 = c(5L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 2L), 
                       V3 = c(8L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L)), 
                  .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

---

Bonus material: besides `dplyr`, you can do this also very efficiently with `data.table` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34753260/2204410) for speed comparisons on large datasets for the different `data.table` methods):

```
setDT(mydf)[V1==3, head(.SD,3)]
# or:
setDT(mydf)[V1==3, .SD[1:3]]
```

Comment: Thank you, Jaap. I appreciate the answer without calling in other packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with dplyr to extract first three rows of each unique value of that column:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(columnName) %>% group_by(columnName) %>% slice(1:3)
```

If you want to extract only three rows when the value of that column, you can try:

```
df %>% filter(columnName == 3) %>% slice(1:3)
```

If you want specific rows, you can supply to slice as `c(3, 4)`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `subset`

```
head(subset(mydf, V1==3),3)
```

#### Update

If we need to extract also one row below the rows where `V1==3`,

```
i1 <- with(mydf, V1==3)
mydf[sort(unique(c(which(i1),pmin(which(i1)+1L, nrow(mydf))))),]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This works perfectly! Now suppose I'd like to extract each row where (ColumnName == 3) AND 1 row underneath each that fit the condition regardless of its contents.