# R subset rows for all occurrences of first variable in column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to create a subset of a large data frame based on two columns, ColA and ColB (below). For each variable in ColA (e.g. A, B, C...), I would like to extract the rows corresponding to each occurrence of the first variable in ColB. Therefore DF1:

```
ColA  ColB  ColC
A     Red     7thing
A     Red     OneBot
A     Blue    BotOne
B     Green   Thing7
B     Green   Twosies
B     Green   Square
B     Yellow  Circle
B     Yellow  Polygon
B     Purple  Triangle
B     White   Octagon
C     Orange  Cube
C     Black   Line
```

Would become DF2:

```
ColA  ColB  ColC
A     Red     7thing
A     Red     OneBot
B     Green   Thing7
B     Green   Twosies
B     Green   Square
C     Orange  Cube
```

I am not concerned about duplicates in ColC, and there is no pattern to the number of occurrences of a variable in ColB. The related subsetting strategies I have found focus on extracting unique cases, but I have neither come across nor been able to devise an approach to permit selecting all occurrences of the first variable type and would be grateful for some assistance.

I have tried

```
DF2 <- DF1[match(unique(DF1$ColB), DF1$ColB),]
```

...and subsetting that targets the variable when the variable content is known (e.g. [Subset first n occurrences of certain value in dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795350/subset-first-n-occurrences-of-certain-value-in-dataframe-in-r)), these are not appropriate seemingly.

Comment: what code have you tried? SO is a coding resource not a coding service

Comment: I have edited my post to include some code, and could put more if helpful, but the problem is not a bug in otherwise appropriate code, which is why I did not include it. Apologies if my question came across as expecting a service, that is not the case, the SO guidelines seemed to suggest including code is not appropriate for every question, which is what I used as my guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power of `ave` in base R, to compare all `ColB` cases to the first `ColB` in each group:

```
dat[with(dat, ColB == ave(ColB, ColA, FUN=function(x) head(x,1) )),]

#   ColA   ColB    ColC
#1     A    Red  7thing
#2     A    Red  OneBot
#4     B  Green  Thing7
#5     B  Green Twosies
#6     B  Green  Square
#11    C Orange    Cube
```

Using your original logic, you could also `merge` back on the non-duplicated records of `ColA/ColB` only:

```
merge(dat, dat[c("ColA","ColB")][!duplicated(dat$ColA),])
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for pointing out the merge tactic as well.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with `aggregate`

```
df[df$ColB %in% unlist(aggregate(ColB~ColA, df, function(x) head(x, 1))[2]), ]

#    ColA   ColB    ColC
#1     A    Red  7thing
#2     A    Red  OneBot
#4     B  Green  Thing7
#5     B  Green Twosies
#6     B  Green  Square
#11    C Orange    Cube
```

Answer (score 3):

As it is a big dataset, approaches using `data.table` are

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[ColB==ColB[1L]], ColA]$V1]
#   ColA   ColB    ColC
#1:    A    Red  7thing
#2:    A    Red  OneBot
#3:    B  Green  Thing7
#4:    B  Green Twosies
#5:    B  Green  Square
#6:    C Orange    Cube
```

Or with `.SD`

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[ColB==ColB[1L]], ColA]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` to accomplish what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(ColA) %>% filter(ColB == first(ColB))
```

First `group_by` `ColA`, then `filter` to keep only rows where `ColB` equals the `first` value in `ColB`. The results using your data is:

```
print(df2)
##Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
##Groups: ColA [3]
##
##    ColA   ColB    ColC
##  <fctr> <fctr>  <fctr>
##1      A    Red  7thing
##2      A    Red  OneBot
##3      B  Green  Thing7
##4      B  Green Twosies
##5      B  Green  Square
##6      C Orange    Cube
```

Comment: No idea why you're downvoted?! This works perfectly fine.

Comment: @thelatemail: thanks for the support! As long as the OP gets what he/she is looking for, I'm good.

Comment: Thanks aichao and thelatemail, this group_by approach is straightforward and useful!