# r data.table - select all rows expect first (in each group)

Tags: r, data.table

Is there any best option to select all row except the first row in each group. I am using head() to select the first row in each group but have a situation where I need to output data except the first row in each group.

I prefer options using data.table package.

```
setDT(mtcars)
mtcars[order(cyl,mpg), head(.SD,2), by=.(cyl)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [data.table - select first n rows within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753050/data-table-select-first-n-rows-within-group)

Comment: I reviewed that thread but I am looking for dynamic option to select all rows within-group except first row. There are some groups where there is no 2nd rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `tail()` and set `n = -1` it will return all but the first row (see `?tail`). You can use this in your command as follows:

```
mtcars[order(cyl, mpg), tail(.SD, -1), by = .(cyl)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just subset `.SD` with `-1`?

```
mtcars[order(cyl, mpg), .SD[-1], by = .(cyl)]
```

If you're looking for all but the last row, there's also the `.N` special symbol.

```
mtcars[order(cyl, mpg), .SD[-.N], by = .(cyl)]
```