# Does unique.data.table with by behave like dplyr::distinct with .keep_all = TRUE?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to get unique rows in a data frame based on one variable, while still choosing which rows (based on other variables) are included.

Example:

```
dt <- as.data.table(list(group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), number = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)))
```

I would normally do this, as it allows me to always keep the row where `number == 1`.

```
dt %>% 
arrange(group, number) %>% 
distinct(group, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This is now too slow, and I'm hoping the data.table equivalent will be faster.

This seems to work:

```
dt <- dt[order(group, number)]
unique(dt, by = c("group"))
```

But I couldn't find anything in the unique.data.table documentation which says that the first row per group is the one which is kept. Is it safe to assume it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about subsetting `.SD` in `j`?

```
library(data.table)
dt[order(group,number),.SD[1],by=group]
#   group number
#1:     A      1
#2:     B      1
#3:     C      1
```

You might also find using `.I` faster because it avoids assembling `.SD`:

In this version, we first assemble a list of row indices using the `.I` special symbol and subset those indices by ones that equal `1` and then take the first (`[1]`) by group. We then access just the indices with `$V1` and subset the original `dt` by that.

```
dt[,.I[number == 1][1], by=group]
   group V1
1:     A  1
2:     B  3
3:     C  6

dt[dt[,.I[number == 1][1], by=group]$V1]
   group number
1:     A      1
2:     B      1
3:     C      1
```

**Edit**:

As @IceCreamToucan points out in the comments, another, easier to read option is with `head.data.table`:

```
dt[order(group,number), head(.SD, 1), by=group]
   group number
1:     A      1
2:     B      1
3:     C      1
```

Comment: I don't understand the second version. Can you break it down a bit?

Comment: If your data is large, running `dt[order(group,number), head(.SD, 1), by=group]` is a quicker option that doesn't require breaking out `.I` and multiple `dt[`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753050/data-table-select-first-n-rows-within-group) `head` is on par with `.I`

Comment: 9314197 See my edit. Also, as @IceCreamToucan points out, `head.data.table` is very highly optimize and a surprisingly good option.

Comment: Ah, thanks both. The indexing option is clever, but I'll stick with head since it's easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/duplicated.html)

> `unique` returns a `data.table` with duplicated rows removed, by columns specified in `by` argument. When no `by` then duplicated rows by all columns are removed.

We can reason from that it does return the first row by each unique group.

To complement options provided by @Ian here is another one which will probably be the fastest one.

```r
setkeyv(dt, c("group","number"))
unique(dt, by="group")
```

At least as of now, because there are possible improvements coming. An example of reducing time from `3.544s` to `0.075s`, it needs an index rather than key, can be found in [unique can be optimized on keyed data.tables #2947](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2947#issuecomment-636472490).